# Check current domain

Tags: php, dns

**How do I know address of opened site?**

My site supports multiple domains on one folder, I have to give a different content corresponding to domain.

Like, if we are on site `http://site.net/`:

```
$string = 1;
```

Or, if we are on site `http://site.com/`:

```
$string = 2;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 2):

Use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (strstr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'],'site.net'))
{
    $string = 1;
}
if (strstr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'],'site.com'))
{
    $string = 2;
}
```